# Debug Blackberry App in Simulator using Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have just started the Hello World App using Blackberry Eclipse Plugin.

I have tried one or two configuration for debug my HelloWorld Blackberry App, but unfortunately I could not..

Can anyone let me know that how can I debug any Blackberry App in simulator using Eclipse Plugin ?

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT :** When I am trying to do so using Debug Configuration option in Eclipse I am getting following error :

**"Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
        org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException"**

with following stacktrace :

```
org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportService.java:151)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportImpl.attach(SocketTransportImpl.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketAttachingConnectorImpl.attach(SocketAttachingConnectorImpl.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.SocketAttachConnector.connect(SocketAttachConnector.java:139)
at net.rim.ejde.A.L.E.doConnect(RIMEIDE:1273)
at net.rim.ejde.A.L.E.debug(RIMEIDE:769)
at net.rim.ejde.A.L.K.launch(RIMEIDE:608)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:866)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1069)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Maybe you got something using the same port as the Simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 30 of this [manual](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12003/BlackBerry_Java_Plug-in_for_Eclipse-Development_Guide--933400-1110042117-001-1.1-US.pdf)

1. In Eclipse®, on the Run menu, click Debug Configurations or Run Configurations.
2. Expand the BlackBerry Simulator item.
3. Perform one of the following tasks:

   To work with an existing launch configuration, under BlackBerry Simulator, click a launch configuration.

   To work with a new launch configuration, right-click BlackBerry Simulator, and click New.
4. Click the Simulator tab.
5. Click the General tab.
6. Click run

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot for your feedback... Can you plz have a look on my edit ?